# Migrating to Hibernate 6: persisting ArrayList

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have following entity definition:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity(name = "trackgeodata")
@Table(name = "trackgeodata")
public class TrackGeodata implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "times")
    private ArrayList<ZonedDateTime[]> times;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "altitudes")
    private ArrayList<int[]> altitudes;  

}
```

So basically storing an ArrayList of ZonedDateTime and int as @Lob. This worked fine.

Now, while trying to migrate to Spring Boot 3.2 and Hibernate 6, I encounter following error:

```
class org.hibernate.type.internal.BasicTypeImpl cannot be cast to class org.hibernate.type.BasicPluralType (org.hibernate.type.internal.BasicTypeImpl and org.hibernate.type.BasicPluralType are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

1. What's the correct way to persist such ArrayLists using Hibernate?
2. How do I ensure that data previously stored in this way is still accessible and compatible with the new way of storing the data?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best way to do it, but apparently in Hibernate 6 you need to be much more explicit in these type of conversions/projections.

In the end, I wrote a custom AttributeConverter for both ArrayLists:

```
    @Converter
    public static class TimesTypeConverter implements AttributeConverter<ArrayList<ZonedDateTime[]>, byte[]> {
        @Override
        public byte[] convertToDatabaseColumn(ArrayList<ZonedDateTime[]> attribute) {
            if (attribute == null) {
                return null;
            }
            return serializeObject(attribute);
        }

        @Override
        public ArrayList<ZonedDateTime[]> convertToEntityAttribute(byte[] dbData) {
            if (dbData == null) {
                return null;
            }
            return (ArrayList<ZonedDateTime[]>) deserializeObject(dbData);
        }

    private static byte[] serializeObject(Object obj) {
        try (ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
             ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(b)) {
            o.writeObject(obj);
            return b.toByteArray();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Serialization error", e);
        }
    }

    // Utility method for deserialization
    private static Object deserializeObject(byte[] bytes) {
        try (ByteArrayInputStream b = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
             ObjectInputStream o = new ObjectInputStream(b)) {
            return o.readObject();
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Deserialization error", e);
        }
    }
    }
```

and assigned the Converter to the field:

```
@Lob
@Convert(converter = TimesTypeConverter.class)
@Column(name = "times")
private ArrayList<ZonedDateTime[]> times;
```